# Bulk insert gives 0 rows affected

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, bulkinsert

The following SQL statement returns "0 rows affected".

The update table is created and the bulk insert is executed without errors. The file I am trying to import is a `;` separated with the headers on the first row. Every row is on a new line.

I have tried several changes but I keep getting the same message on and on:

```
CREATE TABLE DW2.dbo.UPD_TANKINGEN_XXX 
(
    datum NVARCHAR(50),
    tijd NVARCHAR(50),
    kaart NVARCHAR(50),
    kenteken NVARCHAR(50),
    chauffeur NVARCHAR(50),
    bon NVARCHAR(50),
    km_st NVARCHAR(50),
    stationsnaam NVARCHAR(50),
    productnaam NVARCHAR(50),
    volume NVARCHAR(50),
    netto_bedrag_excl_btw NVARCHAR(50),
    factuurnr NVARCHAR(50),
    Debiteurnummer NVARCHAR(50)
)
GO

BULK INSERT DW2.dbo.UPD_TANKINGEN_XXX
FROM 'K:\_DWH\_DW2\Tankdata\XXX.csv' 
WITH (FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR=';', ROWTERMINATOR='\n\r', keepnulls)
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem usually is that UTF-8 is not supported by default. You can try converting this to UTF-16 (Unicode).

You can use a command line utility for this or just open `Notepad++` > `EOL conversion` in `Edit` > Choose `Windows Format`

Comment: Thank you for your reply!

I have checked your path in Notepad++ but the Windows Format is grayed out. I have checked and the file is currently encoded as ANSI.

I also noticed every row ends with a double ; , could that also cause problems?

Comment: actually the problem is the EOL, windows format eol ends in `\r\n`. You can try using `Visual studio code ` file > advanced save options as well

Comment: Again thank you for your valuable reply! I have changed to Rowterminator to `\r\n and changed to encoding to UTF-16 BE BOM and later to UTF-16 LE BOM(using Notepad++. In both cases SQL gives the following error message: 

Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as char. DataFileType will be assumed to be widechar because the data file has a Unicode signature.

Changed the encoding back to ANCI removed the above error message and makes the 0 row(s) affected message return.

Comment: you can't change the `row terminator` without changing the EOL. Try `VS code advanced save options` or open the the CSV with excel and save it. This will convert it into windows format

Comment: Thank you, have have solved the problem bij changing the data file format to .txt.